# Null Column Values in PySpark DataFrame after changing Schema

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns, database-schema

I have a json string. I am currently reading it into a pyspark dataframe.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([json_str])
nested_df = hc.read.json(rdd)
```

Upon doing nested_df.show(20,False) I get:

```
\+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|C_0_0                                                                                          |C_0_1                                                                                            |
\+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|\[{19.765432, 3.13}, {19.765432, 3.13}, {19.765432, 3.13}, {19.765432, 3.13}, {19.765432, 3.13}\]|{{2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567, 2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567}, {2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567, 3.13}}|
\+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My Current Schema is after reading the json_str is :

```
    # root
    # |-- C_0_0: array (nullable = true)
    # |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_0: double (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_1: double (nullable = true)
    # |-- C_0_1: struct (nullable = true)
    # |    |-- C_1_0: struct (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_0: string (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_1: string (nullable = true)
    # |    |-- C_1_1: struct (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_0: string (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_1: double (nullable = true)
```

But I want my schema to be without data loss:

```
    # root
    # |-- C_0_0: array (nullable = true)
    # |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_0: decimal(6,6) (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_1: double (nullable = true)
    # |-- C_0_1: struct (nullable = true)
    # |    |-- C_1_0: struct (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_0: timestamp (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_1: timestamp (nullable = true)
    # |    |-- C_1_1: struct (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_0: timestamp (nullable = true)
    # |    |    |-- C_2_1: double (nullable = true)
```

This is my create table statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CompoundDataTypesSchema.TABLE_NAME ( C_0_0 ARRAY OF ROW ( C_2_0 DECIMAL(6,6) ,C_2_1 DOUBLE ) ,C_0_1 ROW ( C_1_0 ROW ( C_2_0 TIMESTAMP ,C_2_1 TIMESTAMP ),C_1_1 ROW ( C_2_0 TIMESTAMP ,C_2_1 DOUBLE ) ) ) in
 FILES_SERVICE
```

I am expecting the above mentioned table with newly defined schema without data loss. But my current table is:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|C_0_0|C_0_1                                                                                         |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|null |{{2000-12-12 23:30:30.123456, 2000-12-12 23:30:30.123456}, {2000-12-12 23:30:30.123456, 3.13}}|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The C_0_0 column has `NULL` value.

To change the schema I tried the following:

```
def transform_schema(self, schema, parent=""):
        
        if schema == None:
            return StructType()
        
        new_schema = []    
        for f in schema.fields:
            if parent:
                field_name = parent + '.' + f.name
            else:
                field_name = f.name
            if isinstance(f.dataType, ArrayType):
                new_schema.append(StructField(f.name, ArrayType(self.transform_schema(f.dataType.elementType))))
            elif isinstance(f.dataType, StructType):
                new_schema.append(StructField(f.name, self.transform_schema(f.dataType)))
            else:
                new_datatype = self.changeDatatypeforNestedField()
                new_schema.append(StructField(f.name, new_datatype, f.nullable))
        
        return StructType(new_schema)


nested_df_schema = nested_df.schema
        for f in nested_df_schema.fields:
            print("Name: ", f.name)
            col_name = f.name
            if isinstance(f.dataType, ArrayType):
                new_schema = ArrayType(self.transform_schema(f.dataType.elementType, parent = f.name))
                nested_df = nested_df.withColumn("col_name_json", to_json(col_name)).drop(col_name)
                nested_df = nested_df.withColumn(col_name, from_json("col_name_json", new_schema)).drop("col_name_json")
            elif isinstance(f.dataType, StructType):
                new_schema = self.transform_schema(f.dataType, parent = f.name)
                nested_df = nested_df.withColumn("col_name_json", to_json(col_name)).drop(col_name)
                nested_df = nested_df.withColumn(col_name, from_json("col_name_json", new_schema)).drop("col_name_json")
            else:
                new_datatype = self.changeDatatypeforNestedField()
                nested_df = nested_df.withColumn(col_name, nested_df[col_name].cast(new_datatype))]
```

Can someone point me out what might be the issue?

Comment: what is `json_str`?

Comment: Are you sure for the [`decimal`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.DecimalType) format ? Shouldn't it be `decimal(8,6)`?

Comment: json_str is the data.
json_str = [{'C_0_0': [{'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}], 'C_0_1': {'C_1_0': {'C_2_0': "2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567", 'C_2_1': "2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567"}, 'C_1_1': {'C_2_0': "2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567", 'C_2_1': 3.13}}}]

Comment: precision and scale can be anything right?
Can there be a data loss while conversion from double to decimal(6,6)?

Comment: I got the issue. My actual data is Decimal(8,6) and I am typecasting it to Decimal(6,6) so that would give me data loss basically.
Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Decimal is the problem. The schema is not valid, so the field is set to null. You should read the valid json first and change the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data first, and transform the column what you want.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([{'C_0_0': [{'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}, {'C_2_0': 19.765432, 'C_2_1': 3.13}], 'C_0_1': {'C_1_0': {'C_2_0': "2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567", 'C_2_1': "2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567"}, 'C_1_1': {'C_2_0': "2000-12-12 23:30:30.1234567", 'C_2_1': 3.13}}}])

schema = StructType([StructField('C_0_0', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('C_2_0', DecimalType(8, 6), True), StructField('C_2_1', DoubleType(), True)]), True), True), StructField('C_0_1', StructType([StructField('C_1_0', StructType([StructField('C_2_0', TimestampType(), True), StructField('C_2_1', TimestampType(), True)]), True), StructField('C_1_1', StructType([StructField('C_2_0', TimestampType(), True), StructField('C_2_1', DoubleType(), True)]), True)]), True)])
df = spark.read.json(rdd, schema=schema)

df2 = df.withColumn('C_0_0', f.transform('C_0_0', lambda e: f.struct((e['C_2_0'] % 1).cast("decimal(6, 6)"), e['C_2_1'])))
df2.show(truncate=False)
df2.printSchema()

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|C_0_0                                                                                     |C_0_1                                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{0.765432, 3.13}, {0.765432, 3.13}, {0.765432, 3.13}, {0.765432, 3.13}, {0.765432, 3.13}]|{{2000-12-12 23:30:30.123456, 2000-12-12 23:30:30.123456}, {2000-12-12 23:30:30.123456, 3.13}}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- C_0_0: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- col1: decimal(6,6) (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- C_0_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C_1_0: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_0: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C_1_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_0: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_1: double (nullable = true)
```